# Split string with lookahead/lookbehind with empty string

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to split any number string such as `3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971` right after each `0` or group of `0`. However, I would like to keep the 0 after each group.

For example, the string `10203040506070809011` should be split into

```
['10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '11']
```

and the string `3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971` should be split into

```
['3.14159265358979323846264338327950', '28841971']
```

I tried to split apart the string with a positive lookbehind and an empty string:

```
import re
p = '(?<=0+)'

re.search(p, '102030405')
><_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 2), match=''>

'102030405'.split(p)
>['102030405']
```

but this does not split apart the string at all, even though the pattern is matched.

I also tried just splitting apart the string based on the `0` and adding a `0` after the first couple strings, but it seems convoluted and inefficient.

```
l = '102030405'.split('0')
[e+'0' for e in l[:-1]] + [l[-1]]
>['10', '20', '30', '40', '5']
```

Is there any way to split a string based on a lookahead or lookbehind on an empty string? I'm asking about the general case, not just with numbers. For example, if I wanted to split apart `3:18am5:19pm10:28am` into the separate times without losing the `am` or `pm`, and get an array `['3:18am', '5:19pm', '10:28am']`, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: What version of python are you using? I get an error when I try to run `re.search(p, '102030405')`

Comment: Using Python 3.6.1

Comment: How do wish to split ``10020``? ``['100', '20']``, or ``['10', '020']``?

Comment: `['100', '20']`; however, that is how your RegEx already splits it :) and it isn't a hard task to change it up either, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple regex in [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) should suffice:

```
l = re.findall(r'[.1-9]+(?:0+|$)', s)
```

Note:

- `findall` returns **all non-overlapping matches** of pattern in string, **as a list** of strings.
- for each match we want the longest string of digits (or a dot) ending with at least one zero, or the end of the string
- the zeros in the end should not be captured as another match (hence the `(?:...`)

Similarly for you second example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[\d:]+(?:am|pm|$)', '3:18am5:19pm10:28am')
['3:18am', '5:19pm', '10:28am']
```

No need for lookahead/lookbehind magic, or non-greedy matching.

Answer (score 1):

use `re.findall`:

```
l = re.findall(r'(?<![^0])[1-9.]+0*', s)
```

The key is to use a double negation: *not preceded* and *that is not a zero* (to match a preceding zero or the start of the string)

Answer (score 1):

Python `split` requires a non-zero-width match.

You can use `findall` with this regex to get your matches:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'([\d.]+?(?:0+|$))', '10203040506070809011')
['10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '11']

>>> print re.findall(r'([\d.]+?(?:0+|$))', '3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971')
['3.14159265358979323846264338327950', '28841971']
```

`([\d.]+?(?:0|$))` matches digit or dot that ends with `0` or end of line.

---

**Update:**

However I note from your edited question and comments that you're looking for a **generic solution** to use zero-width regex patterns for split operation.

I suggest you install very useful [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) in python. Version 1 of this module provides most of the PCRE features and far outweighs default `re` module.

Installation is pretty straight forward. Just download the tar gzip file from above link and then run:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

From inside the directory that you get after extracting the tar files. (Ignore few warning in install process).

Once `regex` is installed just use this code:

```
>>> import regex

>>> regex.DEFAULT_VERSION = regex.VERSION1

>>> regex.split(r'(?<=[ap]m)(?=.)', '3:18am5:19pm10:28am')
['3:18am', '5:19pm', '10:28am']

>>> print regex.split(r'(?<=0)(?=[1-9])', '10203040506070809011')
['10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '11']

>>> print regex.split(r'(?<=0)(?=[1-9])', '3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971')
['3.14159265358979323846264338327950', '28841971']

>>> print regex.split(r'(?<=0)(?=[1-9])', '10020')
['100', '20']
```

Comment: Is it true that there will never be a situation that I cannot solve without a lookahead or lookbehind? My original question was about matching empty strings with a specific lookahead/lookbehind, but now that I think about it I cannot imagine any case where that is the only choice.

Comment: yes that's right. We can always solve problem by reworking regex as in this example. It would have been surely nice for python to allow empty or zero-width match for match/split.

Answer (score 0):

Anubhava's answer is right. However, it requires to install regex module, which is not needed.

```py
import re
pattern = r"(?<=0)(?=[1-9])"
s = "3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971"
s2 = "10203040506070809011"
re.split(pattern, s)
# ['3.14159265358979323846264338327950', '28841971']
re.split(pattern, s2)
# ['10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '11']
```

You should check the re module page for more details about lookahead and lookbehind.
If I were to explain it. I would say

(?<=...) means something before the separator.

(?=...) means something after the separator.

Thus, (?<=0)(?=[1-9]) means before the separator, which is empty, there should be a zero while after it, a 1 to 9.

Speed comparison between regex and re.

| expression | time |
| --- | --- |
| `re.split(r"(?<=0)(?=[1-9])", s)` | 5.78 ns ± 0.103 ns |
| `regex.split(r"(?<=0)(?=[1-9])", s)` | 6.04 ns ± 0.364 ns |
| `re.split(r"(?<=0)(?=[1-9])", s2)` | 5.83 ns ± 0.061 ns |
| `regex.split(r"(?<=0)(?=[1-9])", s2)` | 6.34 ns ± 1.16 ns |